# shm_open and ftruncate race condition possible?

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-memory, mmap

From the `shm_open` man page:

> A new shared memory object initially has zero length. The size of the
>   object can be set using ftruncate(2). [...] The shm_open() function
>   itself does not create a shared object of a specified size because
>   doing so would duplicate an extant function that sets the size of an
>   object referenced by a file descriptor.

Doesn't this expose the application to a race condition? Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
int fd = shm_open("/foo", CREATE);
if ( fd is valid ) {
  // created shm object, so set its size
  ftruncate(fd, 128);
} else {
  fd = shm_open("/foo", GET_EXISTING);
}
void* mem = mmap(fd, 128);
```

Since the `shm_open` and `ftruncate` calls (together) are not atomic, you could have a race condition whereby one process calls `shm_open` (`CREATE` case) but, before calling `ftruncate`, another process calls `shm_open` (`GET_EXISTING` case) and attempts to `mmap` the object of 0 size and possibly even write to it.

I can think of two ways to avoid this race condition:

1. Use an IPC mutex/semaphore to make the whole thing synchronized, or...
2. If it's safe (per POSIX), call `ftruncate` in both the `CREATE` and `GET_EXISTING` cases.

Which is the preferred method for avoiding this race condition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach (calling `ftruncate` from both) should work, but you need a way to synchronize *use of the contents* of the shared memory segment anyway. As the memory is initially empty (zero-filled) and thus does not contain a valid synchronization object, unless you're going to roll your own with atomics, you need a secondary form of synchronization anyway for controlling access to the shared memory.

I would think normally, rather than having multiple process racing to create-or-open a shared memory segment with a fixed name, you'd want to have an owner process responsible for creating a segment with a *random* name, using `O_EXCL` to avoid random or malicious collisions, and then passing the name, once you've successfully opened it, sized it, and created synchronization objects in it, to the other processes that need to access it.

Comment: This is for a generic/library function, so synchronization of the shared memory itself is left up to the application (since atomic/lockless operations could be sufficient). Also, the name is specified by the caller. `(O_CREATE|O_EXCL)` is always checked as indicated in the psuedo-code. Basically, the logic you suggest would be up to the caller. I think what I'm going to do is call `ftruncate` from both, and use `flock` to ensure the `ftruncate` calls (which could zero the data) do not result in a race condition.

Comment: `flock` is not even POSIX, but even if you used `fcntl` locks or `lockf`, there's no guarantee it works on shared memory file descriptors. There's no need to worry about a race between two `ftruncate` calls; each is atomic, and as long as they're called with the same size, the operation is idempotent.

Comment: Is there documentation that says `ftruncate` if called concurrently from multiple threads or processes is guaranteed to be atomic and idempotent. Such that only one call will zero-initialize the memory, and none of the calls will return until that initialization is complete. I would be surprised if `ftruncate` has that kind of synchronization, which is needed in this case to avoid a race condition (even if it's 1 in a billion). This sounds paranoid, but the applications that will use this are highly parallel and I cannot control how or when they call this function.

Comment: I'll look for the general guarantee, but here's from `truncate`: "If the file previously was larger than length, the extra data is discarded. If the file was previously shorter than length, its size is increased, and the extended area appears as if it were zero-filled." Note that there is no separate zero-filling step. Atomicity is trivial from an implementation standpoint because you have to hold the internal lock on the open file description anyway.

Comment: I saw that in the man page, but my concern is this... Thread `A` enters `ftruncate` and begins zero-initializing the extended area. Meanwhile, Thread `B` enters `ftruncate` while `A` is still initializing or about to start. In order to be 100% safe, `B`'s `ftruncate` call would have to block until `A`'s `ftruncate` call completes the zero-initialization, since neither one can return from the call with zero-initialization still in progress.

Comment: Here's the text I was looking for: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_07. However, unfortunately it is not written to apply to shared memory. I believe this is an oversight, so I'll probably file a bug report.

Comment: Of course (from an implementation standpoint) thread B's `ftruncate` blocks until thread A's `ftruncate` finishes. This is because they have to hold the relevant lock. However, there is no time-consuming zeroing operation to be performed. Implementation-wise, `ftruncate`'s "zero-fill" operation is O(1). It's a zero-fill of the last block/page of the file, and setting the file size field. Further pages are instantiated on use.

Comment: But those are implementation assumptions, not guaranteed. For example, a lock is not *required* for the zero-fill part of the operation. And it's possible preemption could occur before (or even during) the zero-fill depending on how it's implemented. I appreciate your help, but the docs you've linked to do not state guarantees in terms of the behavior I've been asking about.

Comment: Are you clear that the atomicity you want is required for regular files? That is documented in the link I gave you. I agree that the statement of the requirement seems to be missing for shared memory files, but I believe this is an omission, not intentional.

Comment: By the way, from a security standpoint, a lock is basically required for the zero-fill. If there were a way to observe an "extended but not zeroed" file, the process would be able to observe data it does not necessarily have permission to (e.g. freed kernel memory or deleted files belonging to other users).

Comment: I've accepted this answer as the comments have been sufficiently useful.

Answer (score 1):

As @R. alluded to, another issue here is that having created the file there is still a window before contents, such as a mutex, are initialised and ready for use.

A slightly different solution to the above is:

Try to open().
If open() succeeds, simply map() and use with the necessary guarantee (see below) that the contents are already initialised and good to go.
If open() fails, create and initialise a temporary file, then try to hard link() the temporary file as the desired file and unlink() the temporary name.

If link() succeeds, we have now made the initialised file available for ourselves and other processes. If link() fails with EEXIST, another process got there first (unlike rename(), link() fails if the target name exists). Either way, our repeated open() should now succeed with an initialised ready to use file.

With this strategy a race condition clearly exists for initialisation of the temporary file, however provided that the initialisation process is idempotent, not overly expensive on resources, and processes each choose a unique temporary file, this is of no consequence. If multiple initialisation could be an issue, a solution is to split initialisation into a two stage process, with stage one being just a mutex in the file for use to guard against multiple initialisation of the rest of the file during the second stage.